# Probability of union of independent Poisson point processes intersected with bounded set

Tags: probability, measure-theory, independence, point-processes

Let $X=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}X_{i}$ be a union of mutually independent Poisson point processes on $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, and let $B\in\mathscr{B}(S)$ be bounded. Then:
$$\tag{1}
\mathbb{P}(X\cap B=\emptyset)=\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_{i}\cap B=\emptyset).
$$

My question: Why does (1) above hold true?

My thoughts: A sequence of random variables $X_{1},\dots,X_{n}$ are said to be independent if their induced sigma algebras $\sigma(X_{1}),\dots,\sigma(X_{n})$ are independent. That is:
$$\tag{2}
\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}A_{i}\right)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{P}(A_{i}),\quad \forall A_{i}\in\sigma(A_{i}).
$$
I've been trying to relate (2) to (1), but I can't seem to make the connection. What am I missing??

Comment: Your equation (2) should be $\forall A_i \in \sigma(X_i)$ not $A_i \in \sigma(A_i)$.

Comment: @Michael Fixed, thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are mutually independent Poisson Point Processes (PPPs) on the real number line with intensities $\{\lambda_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$. For any region $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ with finite length $|B|$ you can define $N_i(B)$ as the number of points from process $i$ in the region $B$. Then $\{N_i(B)\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are mutually independent random variables and
$$N_i(B) \sim Poisson(\lambda_i \cdot |B|) \quad \forall i \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$$
and the probability that no points from any of the PPPs fall in the region $B$ is:
\begin{align}
P\left[\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}\{N_i(B)=0\}\right] &= \prod_{i=1}^{\infty}P[N_i(B)=0]\\
&=\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} e^{-\lambda_i \cdot Length(B)}\\
&=e^{-(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\lambda_i)\cdot |B|}
\end{align}

---

Here we are using the fact that if $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are mutually independent random variables then for any Borel sets $\{C_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ of the real number line and for any positive integer $n$ we have
$$ P[\cap_{i=1}^n \{X_i \in C_i\}] = \prod_{i=1}^n P[X_i \in C_i] $$
You can take $n\rightarrow \infty$ (and formally use continuity of probability) to conclude
$$ P[\cap_{i=1}^{\infty} \{X_i \in C_i\}] = \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} P[X_i \in C_i] $$
Defining $C_i=\{0\}$ for all $i$ and observing that the event $\{X_i \in \{0\}\}$ is equivalent to the event $\{X_i=0\}$, we get
$$ P[\cap_{i=1}^{\infty} \{X_i=0\}] = \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} P[X_i=0]$$

---

It can be shown that if we define $\lambda = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \lambda_i$ and we assume $\lambda<\infty$, and if we define
$$ N(B) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} N_i(B)$$
then $N(B) \sim Poisson(\lambda)$. In general, the superposition of mutually independent PPPs is again a PPP with the sum rate.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks!! If you would be so kind, I just have two questions. 1) Is it correctly understood that $\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}X_{i}\cap B=\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}N_{i}(B)$? 2) Is there any book or a set of notes that you would recommend reading to learn about point processes?

Comment: Here I am assuming a random variable is a Borel measurable map from the sample space $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$. It does not make sense to take intersections or unions of random variables. The PPP $X_i$ is not a random variable, it represents the actual points. It may make sense to define $X_i(B)$ as including only the points in region $B$. Some people may use notation of unions of PPP, in that case we can interpret $\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} (X_i \cap B) = \cup_{i=1}^{\infty} X_i(B)$ as the points of all processes $i$ in the region $B$, while $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} N_i(B)$ is the number of such points.

Comment: My own notes on PPP are on this link (though it is not extensive, it is contained only in one half-page section III.A). https://ee.usc.edu/stochastic-nets/docs/notes-capacity-large-networks.pdf

Comment: Ahhh, so $\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}(X_{i}\cap B)=\emptyset$ is understood as no points in the region $B$, and that would be the same as $\cap_{i=1}^{\infty} N_{i}(B)=0$, right? Sorry for being a little slow here hahah :)

Comment: And thank you for the link to your notes, I will have a look at them.

Comment: Since $N_i(B)$ are valid random variables, we do not intersect them.  Saying that no points are in region $B$ is the same as saying $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} N_i(B)=0$.

Comment: I think what I'm trying to understand is whether or not $\mathbb{P}(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}X_{i}\cap B=\emptyset)=\mathbb{P}(\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}N_{i}(B)=0)$.

Comment: I do not love the $X_i$ notation, I prefer to work with the random variables $N_i(B)$. Note that for the real number line, a Poisson process of rate $\lambda$ has i.i.d. inter-arrival times that are $Exp(\lambda)$ and is usually represented by a counting process $N(t)$ that is nondecreasing, integer-valued, and increases by 1 at the arrival times (so $N(t)$ represents the number of arrivals during the interval $[0,t]$).

Comment: Perhaps by $\cap_{i=1}^{\infty} N_i(B)=0$ you mean $\cap_{i=1}^{\infty} \{N_i(B)=0\}$.  In that case, and if you want to use the $X_i$ notation,  we indeed have $$P[\cap_{i=1}^{\infty} \{N_i(B)=0\}] = P[\left((\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} X_i)\cap B\right) = \phi] $$ Here I suppose $X_i$ is a "random set" of points on the real number line. The random variable $N_i(B)$ is the number of points in the set $X_i\cap B$. For me it is easier to work with random variables than with random sets.

Comment: It makes sense now. Thank you so much for your amazing help and patience, I really appreciate it!!! :)